# Automatic haskell deriving declaration that lifts

Tags: haskell, typeclass, deriving

Is there a way to have the compiler derive the functionality that I would write manually as:

```
instance Class c => Class (Trans c) where
    foo1 = lift foo1
    foo2 = lift foo2
    ...
    foo999 = lift foo999
    bar1 = \a b c -> lift $ bar1 a b c
    ...
    baz1 = lift . baz1
    ...
```

i.e. when a type of class `Class` is being wrapped in `Trans`, is it possible to get a free instance of `Class` for `Trans` automatically without having to do the heavy lifting :)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you actually want. That instance will work on all `c`, so you only have to write it once. I don't think it can be made any shorter, in the general case.

Comment: But the instance is boring (it just does lifting for all the functions), maybe one could write this concisely (by not having to enumerate all the `fooX = lift fooX` etc.)

Comment: I see, but any alternative (e.g. Template Haskell) looks worse, unless you really have a large number of class methods.

Comment: And if you have enough class methods to justify Template Haskell for that, you should consider redesigning your class.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this; are you looking for `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`? https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#newtype-deriving

Answer (score 1):

If `lift` is itself a type class function, you can write a general definition for all instances of the type class.  Something like:

`instance (Class c, Trans t) => Class (t c)`

Be careful that this doesn't overlap with any other instances, and is what you want for all these types.

As a more complete example, this code works, even though it's results are sometimes surprising.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Inst where

import Control.Applicative (liftA2)

instance (Applicative f, Num n) => Num (f n) where
  (+) = liftA2 (+)
  (*) = liftA2 (*)
  abs = fmap abs
  signum = fmap signum
  fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
  negate = fmap negate
```

Comment: Writing an instance for the application of a type variable to something is *almost never* the right approach, so I don't particularly like it as a suggestion.

Comment: I actually need a specific instance for the bottom-most transformer and I would use lifting only in the rest of the transformers.